# Image appearing over/on top of another image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseclick-event

I am building a Food Cart website for my class. I want there to be an image of a plate, and then once it is clicked have a different image of the food to appear on top of it. I am wondering what sort of javascript or else/if statements can be used to achieve this. If this question is to vague let me know.

I would be using some examples like plate.gif, sandwhich.gif, etc.

Thanks for any feedback. I would be okay with there being a hover affect rather than a on click or mouse pressed event as well.

Comment: Please show your some coding effort.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a simple method of doing this using css the image appears when you click on the plate you can change it to hover if you need http://jsfiddle.net/suwz0zhg/1/

```
<img class="b" src="http://media.npr.org/assets/img/2013/01/10/plate_wide-4764eb8d34c625adfb8c18014a6f43eb300bf079.jpg?s=6" />
<img class="a" src="https://bridor.com/wp-content/uploads/product-images/60HABN-11.png" />
```

CSS

```
 img{
position:absolute;
width:300px;
height:250px;
}

.a{
margin-top:50px;
margin-left:80px;
width:150px;
height:150px;
z-index:-10;
transition:0s 10s;

}

.b:active ~ .a{
z-index:5;
transition:0s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A code like this can be used to toggle the image on and off and will work in most any browser, unlike CSS3. Just click the plate. (I'm borrowing the images from the guy before me)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Special Food Cart</title>
<style type="text/css">
.preview {
position:relative;
}
.preview .plate {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:-1;
}
.preview .food {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
visibility:hidden;
z-index:1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script LANGUAGE="Javascript">
var shownfoodarray = new Array();
function showfood(nom) {
if (!shownfoodarray[nom]) {
shownfoodarray[nom] = 1;
} else {
if (shownfoodarray[nom] == 1) {
shownfoodarray[nom] = 0;
} else {
shownfoodarray[nom] = 1;
}
}
switch (shownfoodarray[nom]) {
case 0:
document.getElementsByClassName("food")[nom].style.visibility = "hidden";
break;
case 1:
document.getElementsByClassName("food")[nom].style.visibility = "visible";
break;
default:
document.getElementsByClassName("food")[nom].style.visibility = "hidden";
}
}
</script>
<div class="preview">
<a href="javascript:showfood(0);">
<div class="plate"><img src="http://media.npr.org/assets/img/2013/01/10/plate_wide-4764eb8d34c625adfb8c18014a6f43eb300bf079.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="plate" border="0" /></div>
<div class="food"><img src="https://bridor.com/wp-content/uploads/product-images/60HABN-11.png" width="200" height="200" alt="food" border="0" /></div>
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think your answer is more better than mine because you have a toggle option but can you provide a fiddle because the one i tried doesn't seem to be working

Comment: here you go. For some reason it doesn't seem to recognize the showfood function in the JS column, only in the HTML column. http://jsfiddle.net/7m31nyem/

Comment: Yup that's more better

Answer (score 0):

since this seems like an assignment for a class, I will try to give you an idea of how to achieve this without actually giving you the answer code.

first of all the images that you are going to use... Besides the plate which is going to be the bottom most image, every other image of foods should be a png type image with transparent background. This you can achieve using photoshop or any decent photo editing software.

Next to achieve the look of various food on the plate, read upon CSS position property and z-index property and display property from any of the online tutorials  like [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp/) etc.

Now for the click effect, place the plate image and using javascript onclick plae the first food image on top of the plate image and using the onclick again on the food image super impose the 2nd food image and so on.

Hope this helps or points you in the right direction. I could give you the code but that would not be fun or fair to other students in your class. Good luck